# Formatting the Powershell script object output?

Tags: azure, powershell

The script does is to Go to each of the Azure Subscription and then list the VM properties and then create the PSObjects to capture the output in a meaningful and useful format.

```
Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    $subscriptionId = $_.Id
    $subscriptionName = $_.Name
     
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

    $VM = Get-AzVM

    # Get NIC id
    $NICId = $VM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].id
    
    # Get NIC
    $NIC = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceId $NICId
    
    # Get public ip id
    $PIPId = $NIC.IpConfigurations.PublicIpAddress.id
    
    # Get public ip
    $PIP = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $PIPId
    
    # Output
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Subscription             = $subscriptionName
        VMName                   = $VM.Name
        VMRG                     = $VM.ResourceGroupName
        VMLocation               = $VM.Location
        IpAddress                = $PIP.Properties.ipAddress
        PublicIPAllocationMethod = $PIP.Properties.publicIPAllocationMethod
        FQDN                     = $pip.Properties.dnsSettings.fqdn
    }
} | Out-GridView
```

However, the result is mixed up and not in the correct format like the below:

**Out-GridView**

[image]

**Format-Table -Autosize**

```
Subscription             : Corp-Azure-Dev-subs
VMName                   : {prod1-build, corpbuild-image, corpplus-build-server, u2api...}
VMRG                     : {corp-prod1-BUILD, corp-PLUS-BUILD-SETUP, corp-PLUS-BUILD-SETUP, ERP-Acorp-DEV...}
VMLocation               : {eastus, east, centralus, westus...}
IpAddress                : 52.44.66.198
PublicIPAllocationMethod : Static
FQDN                     :
```

Comment: Why does `Format-Table -AutoSize` look like `Format-List` in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're outputting multiple object types. From the looks of it the line:

```
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
```

Might be causing the issue.  Remember anything you output is fed down the pipe. So, the likely problem is `Out-Griview` doesn't know what to do with a multi-typed array.  Try sending that like to `Out-Null` to see if it rights the `Out-GridView` result.

Comment: You are correct @steven, that does make sense., tired eyes can cause the issue.
thank you sir.